# Short-hands and Shortcuts of C/C++

Tags: c, shorthand

Are there any resources out there that sort of describe much of the short-hand methods that C and C++ have to offer?  There's alot of "wild" code out there that does not exactly mesh up with what is taught in text books.  For example, many of text books teach you to separate the declaration and initialization of variables, yet I see the contrary happen all the time.

So here is my current stumper:  Does C allow procedures without a type identifier?  Again, text books tell me that I should at very least you a `void` type if no other type is indicated.  However, I have seen the following:

```
procedure(){
//procedure stuff
}
```

where otherwise I have always been taught you must at least do

```
void procedure(){
//procedure stuff
}
```

I find myself in this position alot and I think its a symptom of not had exposure to project/team related work in C or C++.  I have a hard time identifying "compilable code" because many books teach a specific way, but there's more than one way to accomplish the same task in practice.  Thanks.

Comment: K&R C (pre-ANSI) had implicit int functions. This meant that if the return type wasn't specified, it was assumed to be int.

Comment: Your example code is not equivalent. The implied return type would be `int` and not `void`. And even this only in pre-ANSI C. But you ask the wrong question. There is just no way for you to know every possible short-cut idiom or whatever. Those change over time (even core language) and only your ability to identify things you don't know and to look for the answers is important.

Comment: *"many of text books teach you to separate the declaration and initialization of variables"* If C++ textbooks are teaching this, then they are just simply wrong. If C textbooks are teaching this, then they're probably just out of date. C89 required all variables to be declared at the top of the block, so it often was not possible to initialize them at the point of declaration. C99 fixed this, and so the same rules as C++ generally apply.

Comment: Do note that there are a *lot* of bad C and C++ books out there, and then there are a lot more *old* books out there that just haven't been updated to keep up with the evolution of the languages. Just because you read something in a textbook doesn't make it good practice (anymore). Lots of these aren't shorthand "tricks", but rather evolving best practices. Watching answers to Stack Overflow questions is a good way to learn them if you can't obtain a better book. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omitting the return type in a function definition makes the function implicitly returns `int` in C89. Since C99 this is no longer accepted and the implementation could refuse to translate a program with a function definition that omits the return type.

From C99 Rationale document:

> In C89, all type specifiers could be omitted from the declaration specifiers in a declaration. In such a case int was implied. The Committee decided that the inherent danger of this feature outweighed its convenience, and so it was removed.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no explicit return type, it is assumed to be `int`. It is there for legacy reasons.

Another legacy compatibility thing is you can omit argument types, too:

```
add(a, b) { // a and b implicitly int
    return a + b;
}
```

Or you can declare the types of arguments... *differently*...

```
strlen2(s)
const char *s;
{
    int l = 0;
    while(*s++) l++;
    return l;
}
```

I wouldn't leverage any of these features in new code, though, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the parameters. In that case it is a good to use void if no parameters are passed however it is not required, although then it has unknown amount of arguments